# Is there a cli equivalent of Github cli for Bitbucket?

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-cli

I'm looking for a Bitbucket tool that is similar to the Github cli. I'm aware of API, but that's not what I'm looking for. This tool is for the Bitbucket cloud version.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so there is one yet officially. If it's of any use, you could make use of my script https://github.com/psadi/bbcli - it is api based, and its for enterprise.